# can we get the pattern of the given date object

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How to get the `pattern` of the given `date` object

I am getting one `Date` object as a parameter in my method and I want to know the pattern of the date to convert it into user selected timezone.

Comment: an instance of java.util.Date has no information in it about display patterns or time zones.  You will need that to be supplied as an additional method parameters.

Comment: A date object has no format. It's a binary representation. Even if it did, trying to determine a timezone from a formatted string date would be fragile.

Comment: ok, but while i getting the date object which already set a format i want to know that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood what a `Date` means. It's *just* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It has *no concept* of time zone, calendar or text format. If it helps, think of it as being a bit like `int` - an `int` isn't in hex, decimal or binary - it's just a number within a certain range. If you parse "1a" as hex, that gives an indistinguishable result from parsing "26" as decimal. The same goes for `Date`.

Of course, this was already explained in comments to some extent, but your reply of:

> ok, but while i getting the date object which already set a format i want to know that format.

... suggests you didn't really understood it. The concept of "which already set a format" makes no sense in the context of a `Date`.

If you need a particular format to be applied, you should pass the `DateFormat` along as well as the `Date`.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. now i am very much clear about Date class

Answer (score 0):

You can't from the date object itself however (depending on your exact requirements) you could use

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
```

Which will return to you the default style and format for the locale however like I said that's dependant on your requirement...

The alternative is change your method signature to accept the format as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should create [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). `Date` knows nothing about TimeZone.

```
Date date = new Date(); 

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");   
// Set TimeZone
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));   

System.out.println(formatter.format(date));   

// Change timezone   
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));   

System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```